# How to Add New Column Regarding Max Item?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe from a csv item.

```
csv_df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "false").load(csv_path)
```

There is a column as Speed

> Speed: [3, 5, 4, 8, 7, 6, 1]

I want to add a new Column to identify whether this is acceleration or desc.

To achive this first I need to find max item [8] , and mark all items as "A" until this and mark "D" beginning:

> Accel: ["A","A","A","A","D","D","D"]

I can do this with using pandas and numpy library

```
#find max location:
maxloc=np.argmax(csv_pandas_df.Speed)
csv_pandas_df.loc[0:maxloc,'Accel']='A'
csv_pandas_df.loc[maxloc:csv_pandas_df.shape[0],'Accel']='D'
```

Is there any way to achive this via using native Spark DataFrame?

Comment: The data model in SparkSQL (and SQL in general) is a set and it is not ordered. You need to order by something first to get deterministic results. Otherwise that can be done using window functions

Comment: But I see deceleration before the 8.

Comment: But he is showing a column of data? Ordering within that is set. @ollik1

Comment: @thebluephantom Not necessarily, there might be ordering but at least it is not visible in the question. That column could be split among executors e.g. `[3, 5]` and `[4, 8, 7, 6, 1]`

Comment: @ollik1  Are you sure? I have never read that a column can be split over Executors. can you point to official sources? Partitions of RDDs  and DFs, but column splits - may be I am showing my ignorance.

Comment: @thebluephantom Perhaps you are talking about `speed` being an array column and I interpreted `[3, 5, 4, 8, 7, 6, 1]` to mean different values of speed column on different rows (7 rows in this case)

Comment: @ollik1  OK, phew. QED in a loose way: The question is not clear.

Comment: Please clarify the question, based on the chats. Thx

Comment: The important point is just Maximum Item. Until that item acceleration and/or desc dont important. You can think this data as not smooth hat sign(^). Until peak point it is an acceleration and then it is desc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the native spark, but it can be achieved using a UDF(User Defined Function).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import operator

def acc_dec(speeds):
  if len(speeds) is 0:
    return []
  index, value = max(enumerate(speeds), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
  return ["A"]*(index+1) + ["D"]*(len(speeds)-index-1)
acc_dec_udf = udf(acc_dec)

df_accel = csv_df.withColumn("Accel", acc_dec_udf("Speed"))
```